# A plastic bottle of gira (kvass) expanded in the plane: what are the possible consequence?

Tags: bottle-conditioning

A couple of friend just came back from vacation in Lithuania and brought me a bottle of [gira](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kvass). However, the bottle is made of plastic (it looks like a soda bottle) and it suffered from what I guess is traveling in a plane cargo at low pressure: it expanded like a balloon, even the screw cap has a dome.

[image: A expanded bottle of gira.]

What could be the consequences of this expansion on taste, preservation, carbonation or anything else I might have forgotten?

Answer (score 3):

One possible consequence is that the bottle will pop, sending gira all over the place and possibly hurting someone's eardrums.

I don't know if opening the bottle before it bursts helps or, on the contrary, ensures that it bursts in someone's hands.

[image: The late plastic bottle.]

An in the end, you don’t get to know what it tastes like. :’(